# $\bigcup\bigcap \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\} = a$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\bigcup$ $\bigcap$ $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ = $a$. However, I'm assuming that $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ is a set of a set of objects. I'm applying the definition of $\bigcup$ $\bigcap$ to $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ but I'm getting very large, quantified statements.

I'm unsure where to go from here or if I started in an appropriate way. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Comment: note: you need the delimiters to enter math mode the delimiters here are $, place single or double depending on subpart of math mode wanted ( inline or not).

Comment: what do $\cup$ and $\cap$ mean without delimiters? What are you intersecting or taking the union of exactly?

Comment: I am taking the union of the intersection of $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$

Comment: If a is an object, then $\cap${a} is empty or meaningless, but if a is a set, then $\cap${a} = a.

Answer (score 3):

Don't apply the definition of $\bigcup\bigcap$, apply the definitions of $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$ separately.

First: $\bigcap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ is, by definition, the set of all things that are members of all members of $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$; i.e., the set of those things that are in both $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$. There is exactly one such thing, $a$ itself, so $\bigcap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \{a\}$. Therefore $\bigcup\bigcap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\} = \bigcup\{a\}$.

Now, apply the definition of $\bigcup$ to compute $\bigcup\{a\}$. Do you see why the end result has to be $a$?

As a general note: This is a good approach to any problem in set theory, logic, or mathematics in general. Never try to apply a huge, multi-part definition all at once if there's a smaller part to apply first; apply definitions one at a time, in the smallest steps you can think of.

Comment: I understand, and I tried as such. However, I got stuck on the last step, namely applying the definition of $\bigcup$ to $\{a\}$ and getting $a$. It's not clear to me how that happens.

Comment: I get the following $\{z | \exists y (y \in \{a\} \land \{a\} \in y$

Comment: @Adam Define things intuitively first. $\bigcup A$ means "the set of all things that are in elements of $A$". More precisely, $\{z \mid \exists y(y \in \{a\} \wedge z \in y)\}$ (you can tell yours has something wrong because it doesn't involve $z$!) Now, what are the possible choices of $y$? $y$ has to be in $\{a\}$, but there's only one element of that set - so $y$ must be $a$. So really you're looking at $\{z \mid z \in a\}$. Now think about the Axiom of Extension.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigcap\{x,y,z\}=x\cap y\cap z,\ \bigcap\{x,y\}=x\cap y,\ \bigcap\{x\}=x$$
$$\bigcup\{x,y,z\}=x\cup y\cup z,\ \bigcup\{x,y\}=x\cup y,\ \bigcup\{x\}=x$$
$$\bigcap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\{a\}\cap\{a,b\}=\{a\}$$
$$\bigcup\bigcap\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}=\bigcup\{a\}=a$$